# jailbroken ipad3 problems with landscape mode

Tags: ipad, landscape

I published an app in appstore, and works perfectly with all ipads with 5.1 and above. The problems appears when an ipad3 with jailbreak use de app.
The app uses storyboards and the landscape mode is fixed for all the app.
When this ipad use an screen of the game, the orientation changes to portrait mode.
What can i do?